# How to add metatags to a view?

Tags: 7, views, meta-tags

I need to add rel=canonical meta tags to some views. There are a couple of sandbox modules for the [metatag](http://drupal.org/project/metatag) module but I'm looking for a more simple solution.

Couldn't I just use [views_php](http://drupal.org/project/views_php) and [drupal_add_html_head()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_html_head/7)?

Answer (score 2):

Try the [Context Metadata](http://drupal.org/project/context_metadata) module. It can add metadata to node and non-node pages. The following metadata tags can be set according to a context: Title, Description, Keywords and **Canonical URL**.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add meta tags to a view without adding or writing a module, you could just do this. Add a block with the following PHP code and set the block visibility that view only.

```
<?php
$element = array(
  '#tag' => 'meta', // The #tag is the html tag - <link />
  '#attributes' => array( // Set up an array of attributes inside the tag
    'name' => 'description', 
    'content' => 'Your view description.',
  ),
);
drupal_add_html_head($element, 'yourviewname_meta_desc');
?>
```